# Apache Camel Kafka - LAST_RECORD_BEFORE_COMMIT vs. LAST_POLL_RECORD

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am implementing manual transactional processing within Camel and Kafka. For example, I have 3 Kafka consumers with 3 subroutes like in the picture below:

[image]

Those 3 subroutes includes code as follows:

```java
Boolean lastOne = exchange.getIn().getHeader(KafkaConstants.LAST_RECORD_BEFORE_COMMIT, Boolean.class);
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(lastOne)) {
    //write into the database
        }
```

It causes the loss of the message because within the "if" statement there is also a commit into the database. Does it mean that the check for LAST_RECORD_BEFORE_COMMIT must be one level higher in the Kafka consumers? or should I use LAST_POLL_RECORD?